# Ajax Codeigniter form doesn't work in IE?

Tags: ajax, forms, internet-explorer

This is the ajax code for the form submission:

```
$('form[class^="ajaxsubmit_"]').live('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var classname = $(this).attr('class');
    var classnamesplit = classname.split("_");

    var container = classnamesplit[1];

    if (container == 'parent'){
        container = $(this).parent();
    }
    $(container).show();
    $(container).html('<img src="public/images/web/ajax.gif"/>');
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(container);
});
(function($){
    jQuery.fn.ajaxSubmit =
        function(container) {
            var url = $(this).attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                    url: url,
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(msg) {
                                $(container).html(msg);
                        }
                   });
            return this;
         };
})(jQuery);
```

This is like a general function for all forms, it reads the action and sends the data to it. Then outputs in the parent or the specified div. It works perfectly fine in Chrome, Firefox and Opera. How can I solve this?

Comment: `$('form[class^="ajaxsubmit_"]')` why not setup single class and use 
`$('form.ajaxsubmit')` ?

Comment: instead of doing things like `classname.split("_");` use `data` attributes. access like `$(this).data('container')`

Comment: @eicto Why? Doesn't `classname.split("_")` work in IE?

Comment: because it is incorrect usage of class if I had an aswer i would to  answer, I just suggest proper way of doing things, if you follow **dao** it should work fine in any browser :)